# Problem when modifying axios default headers globally - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

In **main.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + Vue.auth.getToken()
};

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL; //TODO: append the trailing slash

// Add modified axios instance to Vue prototype so that to be available globally via Vue instance
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

Everything works fine up to this point. (I am able to successfully login and store the token)

Now, I have another component that fetches a list of users from the server through an ajax call performed on component’s created() lifehook.
My problem is that when I am trying to access `this.$http` in component I get back a 401 error response from the server because `Authorization` header is not available to the request headers (although I have pre-configured axios.defaults.headers.common)

The strange thing is that if I hit the refresh button on my browser then the token is correctly attached to the request header and the list of users is successfully fetched**.**

Could anyone please explain to me why is that happening?

Comment: Can you post the code of the component that is using Axios?

Answer (score 2):

You can user axios request interceptors to add your headers globally

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
// Do something before request is sent
  return config;
}, function (error) {
// Do something with request error
   return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

you can access your current request readers using **config.header** and you can set the headers to the request like

```
config.headers = {
   'Authorization': 'JWT ' + Vue.auth.getToken()
}
```

https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class to add the headers of your choice globally.

```
import axios from 'axios';

/**
 * A wrapper around an axios instance, preconfigured to have a base URL and auth headers
 */
class Axios {
    constructor(baseUrl, bearerToken) {

        return axios.create({
            baseURL: baseUrl,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
            }
        });
    }
}

export default Axios;
```

Then in your app.js

```
import { Axios } from 'my/class'


const myService = new Axios('baseURL', 'bearerToken');
```

Comment: can you do a export default new Axios('baseurl', 'token') so that you can use it directly instead of having to declare it every time?

Comment: then, let result = await myService.request()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [asios.create](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance)?

`http/index.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import env from '../config/env'
import store from '../store'

export default (() =>
  axios.create({
    baseURL: env.API_HOST,
    headers: {
      common: {
        Authorization: store.getters['user/getAuthToken']
      }
    }
  }))()
```

`main.js`:

```
import http from './http'

Vue.prototype.$http = http
```

Additionally I use a store action to update the axios client:

```
updateHTTPClientAuthToken () {
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = this.getters.getAuthToken
}
```